# Как отбросить нули у int

Tags: java

Мне нужно убрать нули слева у чисел (int). Как это сделать?

Пример того что мне нужно:

```
было | стало
10   | 1
100  | 1
200  | 2
300  | 3
400  | 4
401  | 401
410  | 41
```

Также нужно посчитать, сколько нулей алгоритм отбросил.

Comment: Вам поможет замечательный оператор `%`. `% 10` вообще решит все проблемы.

Comment: Просто делите на 10 пока остаток от деления больше 0, и считайте сколько раз разделили.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
int i = 4011100;
int k = 0;
while (i % 10 == 0) {
    i = i / 10;
    k++;
}
System.out.println("Result:" + i + " Zeroz:" + k);
```

> Result:40111 Zeroz:2

Answer (score 6):

Концептуально для определения количества отброшенных нулей (при условии, что вы не отбрасываете их *сами*) проще всего, наверное, поделить первое число на второе (вы получите степень десятки) и взять десятичный логарифм (получите показатель степени). Не забудьте выполнить округление, т. к. вычисления с плавающей запятой не вполне точны.

(Для отбрасывания нулей, разумеется, вам нужна операция взятия остатка, чтобы проверить, ноль ваша последняя цифра или нет, и деления, чтобы отбросить её. Но это уже до меня порекомендовали другие.)

---

Прагматически, если у вас есть числа в строковом представлении, проще не конвертировать в число, а сканировать строку с конца и подсчитывать встреченные нули. Но это решение, на мой вкус, слишком завязано на свойства десятичного представления целых чисел.

Comment: А код в Java представите? Хотябы простой чтобы показать суть. И это не строковое представление Integer, Long.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров: `Math.round(Math.log10(first / second))`?

Answer (score 1):

Также удаление последних нулей в числе можно сделать с помощью регулярных выражений без циклов:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 41002000; // либо записать число сразу в String
    String num = Integer.toString(x);
    String new_num = num.replaceAll("0*$", "");
    System.out.println(num + " -> " + new_num +
            ", deleted: " + (num.length()-new_num.length()));
}
```

---

Пример работы на [ideone](http://ideone.com/2VCawR):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: За что минусы? Самое явное решение с циклом уже написано, я предложил альтернативное через регулярные выражения.

Comment: зачем учить людей плохому?

Comment: @Etki это **альтернативный** способ решения

Comment: Вот именно зачем учить плохому, представьте вам надо законвертить числа от -int min до +int max, оно и без того медленно а вы предлагаете напрячь оперативку, cpu приводом к строкам. Да еще регулярным выражением...

Comment: Распечатывать сообщения на принтере, чтобы передать их в другое приложение сканированием - это тоже альтернативный способ решения

Answer (score 1):

В java так :

```
  replaceAll(0,"");
```

Comment: Читайте внимательно описание и решение людей. Это не String:) + replaceAll ??? Тема старая и решение вполне быстрое и рабочее.

Comment: Я новый участник я понял свою вину больше не повторится

Comment: Да ладно, помощь приветствуется.